# extract points from line in python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

i'm working on a 3d scanner using raspberry pi and i compare each image with other image that has a difference which is laser line

here is an example 
image1 : http://s18.postimg.org/z2kra0vy1/image.jpg

image2: http://s13.postimg.org/dqye3q6vr/image.jpg

the result image : http://s18.postimg.org/rzhh85fw9/final.jpg

so now how i can extract the coordinates of laser line from the result image in python without using nested loops ?

here is the code i use to get the difference

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import  ImageChops

im1 = Image.open("11.jpg")
im2 = Image.open("22.jpg")

diff = ImageChops.difference(im2, im1)

diff.show()
```

Comment: You need to search for the term `python feature extraction`. However, I hope you are not working in JPG because it is lossy thus noisy. In your "result image" I'd be hard pressed to point to where the feature begins because of the fuzz.

Comment: thanks , i will search and trying to find any solution @msw